# How can I write Collatz conjecture by SymPy?

Tags: sympy, collatz

I was going to write a SymPy function which takes a natural number and returns the step number of Collatz conjecture of the arg. The Python version is here:

```
def collatz(n: int):
    step = 0
    while n != 1:
        n = n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3 * n + 1
        step += 1
    return step

print(collatz(27))
```

It prints 111.
How about SymPy version? I feel sympy.Lambda() should have a recursive feature, similar to recursive call of procedual programming. Is there a good way?

- Just calling `collatz()` with a `sympy.Symbol()` instance (obviously) went into iloop.
- `sympy.series.sequences.RecursiveSeq()` does only backward reference with constant decrements.

Comment: Someone suggested this [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16167) and I left comments there, too, and a suggestion for a symbolic-capable version.

Comment: Can you turn the generator to `sympy.Lambda` instance which returns the step number? I failed to do something like it.

Comment: It's not really clear what the function you gave is not doing for you. What do you want to be different?

Comment: ```
from sympy import *

f = Function('f')
x = var('x')

y = x * f(x)
z = y / f(x)
print(z.subs({x: 1}))
```
This code left `f` undefined but print `1`. Collatz can require much time to calculate, so I want to leave it uncalculated when it is not required finally. So I want to make it a sympy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `f(x)` be the symbolic collatz result. Do a substitution followed by a replacement to replace any non-symbolic results:

```py
>>> f=Function('f')
>>> eq = f(x)
>>> eq.subs(x, 270)
f(270)
>>> _.replace(lambda x: x.func == f and x.args[0].is_Integer, lambda x: collatz(x.args[0]))
42
```

If you don't want to do it like this and want automatic evaluation, then you will have to write a SymPy class deriving from Function that has an eval method that detects when the input is an Integer. You can look at any function to see how this is implemented, e.g. see the source code for `cos`.